# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061][WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, django, localhost

What exactly does this error mean and how can i fix it, am running server on port 8000 of local host.

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: This error can also arise if there is no server listening on that port. Are you sure your server is actually running? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is firewall running on the server? If so, that may be blocking connections. You could disable firewall or add an exception on the server side to allow connections on port 8000.

Comment: disabled firewall on my private network which am on but the issue still persist

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set my default VS-Code internal terminal profile to `Command Prompt`:
[image]

For more details, please refer to [this full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73280867/12298276).